# Trouble casting integer object to primitive type

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, casting

I'm trying to do this challenge on codewars : https://www.codewars.com/kata/554ca54ffa7d91b236000023/train/java
I changed the original array into an arraylist, but then I have to use the values in arrayist to do some comparisons with primitive types.

I tried to cast the Integer objects using (int) but there's still casting errors. When I tried to do (int)(arrList.get(j)).equals(current), it tells me boolean can't be converted to int.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class EnoughIsEnough {

    public static int[] deleteNth(int[] elements, int maxOccurrences) {
      ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(elements));
    for (int i = 0; i < arrList.size(); i++) {
      int current = (int)arrList.get(i);
      int occurrences = 1;
      for (int j = i + 1; j < arrList.size(); j++) {
        if (arrList.get(j).equals(current) && occurrences >= maxOccurrences) {
          arrList.remove(j);
        } else if (arrList.get(j).equals(current)) {
          occurrences++;
        }
      }
    }
    int arr[] = new int[arrList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrList.size(); i++) {
      arr[i] = (int) arrList.get(i);
    }
    return arr;
    }

}
```

It compiled but the test shows : class [I cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer ([I and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Comment: `[I` is an array type so you're not going to be able to cast it to an `Integer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(elements)` does not do what you think it does, it returns a list of containing the int[] array, not the elements of the array. You can not create a list of primitives. If you want to use List you must first convert the `int` to `Integer`.

You can get a List of `Integer` with

```
List<Integer> arrList = Arrays.stream(elements).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

however, you still have a bug in your program where you will skip numbers.

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < arrList.size(); j++) {
  if (arrList.get(j).equals(current) && occurrences >= maxOccurrences) {
    arrList.remove(j); // This shortens the list causing us to skip the next element
    j--; // One hackish way is to go back one step

  } else if (arrList.get(j).equals(current)) {
    occurrences++;
  }
}
```

One solution is to loop backwards instead

```
for (int j = arrList.size() - 1; j > i; j--) {
  if (arrList.get(j).equals(current) && occurrences >= maxOccurrences) {
    arrList.remove(j);
  } else if (arrList.get(j).equals(current)) {
    occurrences++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a library I need to import? When I used your code it's telling me cannot find symbol.

Comment: No. Which symbol is it complaining about?

Comment: The code is using `java.util.Arrays` which I think you code includes with `java.util.*` and `java.util.stream.Collectors`. Both since Java 8 I think.

Comment: Fancy codes never work with me. I just used a loop to manually add the values into the list and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(elements));
```

with

```
List<Integer> arrList = Arrays.stream(elements).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```